# Error when executing "perform tests" in Roo

Tags: maven, spring-roo, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm using Spring Roo in STS and when I run the command "perform tests" I get the following error:

```
Cannot run program "mvn.bat" (in directory "C:\SS workspace\hello"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

Does anyone know what's the problem? I have maven installed properly and the PATH env set to MAVEN_HOME/bin

Comment: Try change STS maven settings and restart your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My Guess is that it chokes on the whitespace character in the current directory (although it shouldn't)

Answer (score 1):

[Known bug.](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/ROO-1663) Instead use the 'Run As > JUnit Test' command

> STS provides via the 'Run As > JUnit Test' a more visual interface
>   which I prefer, but some may still prefer the "Roo Shell"

Answer (score 0):

If you are on windows 7- 64 bit machine, check if your mavan is on path. Omit MAVAN_HOME and try adding full path.